# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10(Django)

Tags: mysql, django

[error in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPiQA.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX4V5.png)

I tried to create a project where to manage a garage, but when I create the model in application"utiliser", I got this problem. Thanks!

Comment: This means you try to initial an int object with a  non-numeric value, for example, `int("a")` will raise the same error.Check your code, I think an error like this is easy to find and solve.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are trying to assign string `client` as the default value for your ForeignKey. ForeignKeys are represented as integers and that is why you get this error. You can assign id value of the foreign object (if exists), or use `null=True` which will make default `NULL`. If there is no data at all in this object, then remove default value, migrations and flush database, then you will get not-nullable ForeignKey field.